Restart all systemctl services that starts with the letters "lc-"
I want to list all services that starts with the letters lc-.
Then I want to restart them.
How can I attchive this?
I was thinking something like:
systemctl -l | grep ?? | systemctl restart ???

You can list the unit files with..
systemctl list-unit-files | grep -Eo '^lc-.*\.service'

-E means you are going to use an extended regex expression.
-o means you want only the matching parts.
'^lc-.*\.service' is the regular expression to get only those services that start with 'lc-'.
Then to restart all of them you can use wildcards in your command
systemctl restart 'lc-*'


@kos OP did ask for 'lc' not 'ls' as far as I can see.  '^lc-[^ ]*' will capture lines starting with 'lc-' and omit the extra info after the first word.  I've made the other changes you've suggested.

Note that restart is not limited to restarting already started/running units but will also start those which aren’t already started/running if they match that pattern.

(Small nit: you don't really need to use -E as you're not using any extended regex feature)

Yeah they asked for -lc in the title and for -ls in the body of the question, but they since then edited the body to match the title. I guess we both just looked at one and not at the other... and fair enough I missed the point in matching until the first space, my bad. It looks better now, I removed my downvote; I would like to also upvote this,my problem with this now, as @Raffa pointed out is that stopped services matching the pattern will be started, I think you should point this out in the answer.

... there's try-restart which according to the man page only restarts already-running units

Using @steeldriver 's last suggestion along with a pattern such as lc-*.service, to restrict the targets to only services as asked in the question, is the best way to tackle this and makes jumping through hoops the way I did in my answer unnecessary: systemctl try-restart 'lc-*.service'

systemctl can filter by unit type and unit state on its own, not to mention it can print the output as a JSON file, which allows extremely robust parsing, so you could print only running services as a JSON file:
systemctl --type=service --state=running --output=json

filtering out elements whose unit key's value doesn't start with lc-, printing just the unit's name:
jq -r '.[] | .unit | select(test("^lc-"))'

passing the output to xargs -r + sudo systemctl restart (the -r switch will prevent xargs from running sudo systemctl restart in case no running service matching the criteria was found; note that valid unit names can't include whitespace per systemd's specifications so piping the output to xargs -r directly is safe):
xargs -r sudo systemctl restart

Putting everything toghether:
systemctl --type=service --state=running --output=json |
    jq -r '.[] | .unit | select(test("^lc-"))' |
    xargs -r sudo systemctl restart


sudo systemctl --type=service --state=running --output=json | sudo jq -r '.[] | sudo .unit | sudo select(test("^ls-"))' | sudo xargs systemctl restart
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting end of file (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
.[] | sudo .unit | sudo select(test("^ls-"))
jq: 1 compile error
Too few arguments.

@Europa You're adding way too many sudo and some of them are breaking parsing, just add a sudo before the systemctl command: systemctl --type=service --state=running --output=json | jq -r '.[] | .unit | select(test("^ls-"))' | xargs sudo systemctl restart

@Europa "Too few arguments" is because there were no results for the expression "^ls-" ... You needed "^lc-" instead.

@Raffa Thanks for implicitly pointing out the possible issue, luckily nothing would break if no service matches the regex in this case, but to be honest it's incidental, I didn't explicitly cater for that :) however they're also putting sudo inside the jq expression, so maybe there are services starting with lc- and the jq expression, broken as is, is breaking the pipe. On that note I have yet to figure out if they want to match lc- or ls-, they wrote two different things in the title and in the body of the question...

You're welcome, that's a minor issue which is not your fault ... However, your solution is as accurate, controlled, and efficient as it gets IMHO
